# Swift: How can I create a secondary Bar attached under my navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

The reason I want this second bar is because I want it to stay in the totality of my project. I want to have this bar under my navigationbar and stay constant throughout the run of my project. [image]

The top red bar is the nav bar, and the top green bar is my bar. They will have different background colors. The orange/gray box represent the screens that will appear under these bars.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you're going to put in it but a first thought would be to create a UIView then use auto layout and constraints to keep it snugged up against the navigation bar.

Comment: I'm doing that now, and it works for one screen, but I want it to transport me to other screens.

Comment: @Patrck Lynch has a good idea below.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd create a view controller called something like `MyToolbarViewController` and add its view as a child of your navigation controller.  Use Auto Layout to give it a constant height, leading, trailing and top layout guide constraints.  This will allow this view to remain in place while the navigation controller performs its normal transitions in which navigation bars are replaced with that slide/fade animation.  To adjust the content in each view controller pushed onto the navigation controller, adjust insets or top layout guide constraints.

Comment: How do I add my view as a child of my navigation view controller?

Comment: You could create a subclass of `UINavigationController` and set it up in `viewDidLoad`, or if you have some kind of parent view controller that owns a child navigation controller, you could set it up there and then add the view to the child navigation controller.  You might even be able to get away with setting it up from one of the view controllers in the navigation controller's view controller stack, but you'd have to manage that and make sure its always the root view controller and never performs the same setup twice.  It's up to you really! :)

Comment: I'm confused. Won't a UIViewController not be able to be a child of a UINavigationController?

Comment: It's not the typical use case, but there's no reason why it wouldn't be—`UINavigationController` is just a subclass of `UIViewController`.